# How to hide a custom loading icon after a certain amount of time (android)?

Tags: android, progressdialog, countdowntimer

I am currently implementing my own custom progress dialog, where I call show and hide once a result comes in/error occurs. However, I want to implement a custom method that says if the progress dialog has not hidden after 10 seconds no matter what, hide it and put up an alert.

This is my custom progress dialog with my method that works but not entirely.

```
public class CustomProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {

    private AnimationDrawable animation;
    private CountDownTimer cTimer = null;
    private Context mContext;
    public CustomProgressDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_dialog);


        ImageView la = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animation);
        la.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_progress_dialog_animation);
        animation = (AnimationDrawable) la.getBackground();

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();
        animation.start();
        startTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public void dismiss() {
        super.dismiss();
        animation.stop();
        if(cTimer != null) {
            cTimer.cancel();
        }
    }

    //timer added just in case progress dialog does not stop on its own
    private void startTimer() {
        cTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                dismiss();
                AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
                alert.showAlertDialog(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.loadingErr), mContext.getString(R.string.loadingErrTxt), 3);
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        animation.stop();
        cTimer.cancel();
    }
}
```

This is how I implement it in the activity/fragment:

```
private void showProgressDialog() {
        customProgressDialog = new CustomProgressDialog(this);
        customProgressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        customProgressDialog.show();
        //so it cannot be closed by user first one lets back button cancel it
        //customProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        customProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);

    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if(customProgressDialog != null) {

           //customProgressDialog.hide();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:** This is a second option I tried it still does not stop the alert from popping up which makes me think the timer is still going even on cancel.

This is the activity:

```
private void autoProgressShutdown() {
        Runnable progressRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                customProgressDialog.cancel();
                callAlert();
               }
        };

        Handler pdCanceller = new Handler();
        pdCanceller.postDelayed(progressRunnable, 10000);
    }

    private void callAlert() {
        AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
        alert.showAlertDialog(this, getString(R.string.loadingErr), getString(R.string.loadingErrTxt), 3);

    }


    private void showProgressDialog() {
        customProgressDialog = new CustomProgressDialog(this);
        customProgressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        customProgressDialog.show();
        //so it cannot be closed by user first one lets back button cancel it
        //customProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        customProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        autoProgressShutdown();

    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        customProgressDialog.cancel();
        if(customProgressDialog != null) {

           customProgressDialog.hide();
        }
    }
```

In the custom dialog edited the file to remove all the timer stuff and added this:

```
 @Override
    public void setOnCancelListener(OnCancelListener listener) {
        super.setOnCancelListener(listener);
        dismiss();
    }
```

Possible Issues:
-not sure if memory leak issues since I am not destroying it

Definite Issues:
-if the Progress dialog is hidden the alert still pops up after 10 seconds which means either cancel did not get called
-Also, if I switch screens not sure if the cancel is enough to destroy the timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Handler#postDelayed` to make something happen later on a given thread, and you can use `Handler#removeCallbacksAndMessages` to cancel pending tasks. If you call it with `null`, it just cancels anything pending on the handler if you've got some stuff that you need to prevent in the posted task.

Here's your dialog, but properly self-terminating:

```
class SuicideDialog extends Dialog{
  private Handler mAutoTerminationHandler;

  @Override
  public void onShow(){
    mAutoTerminationHandler = new Handler();
  }

  @Override
  public void show(){
    super.show();
    mAutoTerminationHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
      dismiss();
    }, 666L);
  }

  @Override
  public void dismiss(){
    mAutoTerminationHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    super.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Or, you can put the lifecycle listening into its own class:

```
class ShownTaskListener implements OnShowListener, OnDismissListener {
  private Handler mHandler;

  @Override
  public ShownTaskListener(Handler handler, Runnable showTask){
    mHandler = handler;
    mShowTask = showTask;
  }

  // from OnShowListener
  @Override
  public void onShow(){
    mHandler.postDelayed(mShowTask, 666L);
  }

  // from OnDismissListener
  @Override
  public void onDismiss(){
    // get rid of all pending actions in the Handler
    mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
  }
}
```

And then, you can use it to self-dismiss any `Dialog` by attaching this listener with `Dialog#setOnShowListener` and `Dialog#setOnDismissListener`.